# Reconstructing polynomial differential equation from its solution

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, solution-verification

The Picard-Lindelöf theorem states that a differential equation with $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique solution if $F$ is differentiable given some initial condition $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I am interested in the inverse problem. Given a solution $\gamma(x_0,t)$ for the maximal interval of existence, can we identify the ODE, i.e. $F$. Since this is impossible in general, I restrict to polynomial vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of degree $d$, i.e. $F \in \mathbb{R}[[x_1,...,x_n]]^d$. These functions are specified by $M={ \begin{pmatrix} N+d \\ d \end{pmatrix} }^{ N }$ real constants.

---

Is the following statement true?

*Theorem:* Given a trajectory $\gamma(x_0,t): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that the trajectory has at least $M$ different points $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^M \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. We also know the first derivative at the trajectory at these points $\dot{\gamma(x_i)} \quad \forall i =1,...,M$ which are also assumed to be different.
We can reconstruct the polynomial vector field $F$ giving rise to the trajectory just by solving for the coefficients in the standard way.

Comment: Is this an autonomous differential equation $y' = F(y)$?  For polynomial $F$, the solutions will typically blow up at finite time.  Are you assuming this trajectory exists for all time?  You certainly can't expect to reconstruct $F$ if the points sampled are all in the same hyperplane.

Comment: Since each data point supplies $2N$ constraints, it should only require $M/(2N)$ points to uniquely specify the vector field.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It is autonomous. It is not necessary that the solution exist for all times for my goal. Thanks for the comment